# screen orientation inherited by child activity

Tags: android, android-activity, screen-orientation

I have a Base activity(extends `AppCompactActivity`) which is extended by all the activities. My question is if I set `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` from the Manifest file to the base activity, why is it not set to all the activities that are extending this activity. This is my manifest file

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".BaseActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity android:name=".OtpActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to set orientation for all the child activity, perhaps it's better to use code as below on the base activity

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

In the Manifest, it is targeting the exact activity instantiated e.g. if it is for .BaseActivity, then only the actual .BaseActivity launch will have it's xml configuration. The value set in the xml doesn't apply beyond the code inheritance hierarchy, but instead each activity launch will need to have it's own tag in manifest.xml. Inheritance doesn't apply here in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: can you please explain as to why the inheritance is not applied in the Android manifest, is it for a reason or is it because it cannot be done. Thanks

Comment: It's the way Android is design where the content within XML is applied to specific Activity. Imagine if it allows inheritance, the if both activities has the orientation set, then it would need to resolve the orientation. This would make things more complicated. Hence it is not design for that.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** In `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` is properties of every screen or activity which is register in manifest file so if you dont mention this property in every activity in the manifest then it will take default so we have to mention this property for each and every activity, even if activity extend by other activity which mentions this property  Inheritance doesn't apply here in the AndroidManifest.xml.